# unable to open openmpi ? Terminal / OSX 10.9.1

Tags: terminal, osx

Hi I am trying to simulate an example of a software using terminal on OSx 10.9.1. When I execute examples the terminal said Bus error:10 and some errors abput openmpi.
I downloaded Openmpi versions 1.6.5, 1.7.4 and lastly 1.4.5 from this website `http://www.open-mpi.org`  But now, the terminal say

```
mca: base: component_find:
```

`unable to open /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_env: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_env.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_jmap_t_class`

Please help me how can I fix it?

Comment: your binary does not fit your system, try to get a proper one.

Comment: @bersch how can I do it please?

Comment: I'd remove/deinstall all openmpi binaries. Such files are often responsible for other errors. Find a binary, that fits your system, or build it from source like explained here: [Installing Open MPI on Mac OS X](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+Open+MPI+on+Mac+OS+X).